# Eclipse on Ubuntu: Web Deployment Assembly only copy folders without content

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, ubuntu

I am running tomcat7 inside of eclipse on ubuntu. I have set Web Deployment Assembly correctly. But when I start tomcat7 inside of eclipse, it creates all the folders under /tomcat-7.x.x/wtpwebapps, but not content (.class, .properties, .xml...) are copied. What am I missing? The same application builds and runs fine in Windows, only have problem in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a permission thing. Also I recommend install tomcat manually instead of running apt-get.
Either https://askubuntu.com/questions/17223/permissions-problem-when-copying-files-to-usr-share-tomcat6 or http://www.frattv.com/tomcat-can-t-start-from-ide-eclipse-luna-wtp-intellij-idea-in-ubuntu/ will work.